# Simple Client Server program

Tags: java, network-programming

I making an elementary project based on TCP/IP where server listens to the client and then provides a capital sentence of the incoming data.

Server.java:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
public class Server 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(7948);
        Socket s= ss.accept();
        System.out.print("Server connected\n");

        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream (s.getInputStream());
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream (s.getOutputStream());

        while(true)
        {
            int a = bis.available();
            byte b[] = new byte[a];
            bis.read(b);
            String str = new String(b);
            str = str.toUpperCase();
            b = str.getBytes();
            bos.write(b,0,b.length);
            bos.flush();

            if(str.equals("BYE"))
                break;
            else
                continue;
        }
        System.out.print("\nServer Disconnecting");
        String str = "Adios Amigo";
        bos.write(str.getBytes());
        bos.flush();

        bis.close();
        bos.close();
        ss.close();
        s.close();
    }
}
```

Client.java:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
public class Client 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        BufferedReader clientStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String str; 
        int a;
        byte[] b;

        Socket s = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 7948);

        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream (s.getOutputStream());
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream (s.getInputStream());

        one:while(true)
        {
            str = clientStream.readLine();
            b =str.getBytes();
            bos.write(b);
            bos.flush();

            a=bis.available();
            b = new byte[a];
            bis.read(b);
            str = new String (b);
            str.trim();
            System.out.print("The server says: "+str);
            if (str.equals("BYE"))
            {
                bis.read(b);
                str = new String (b);
                System.out.print("The server says: "+str);
                break one;
            }
        }

        s.close();
        clientStream.close();
        bos.close();
        bis.close();
    }
}
```

The program is working properly except for one problem, output at client side comes after two inputs. It means that I have to give two inputs from client sides to get the first output, and this continues. I am unable to track the bug.
Can anyone please help ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in the client, you send data to the server, and then immediately call `a.available()` - this function does not wait for data to be sent from the server. since the server is unlikely to have responded with data by the time the `.available()` is called, the function returns zero.

because of this, your byte array `b` (please use more descriptive variable names in the future) is of length zero.

once the array of size zero is created, you finally wait for data by calling `bis.read()` - .read() is a *blocking* call. it will wait for data from the server. this data is not actually read, because the array you are reading in to is size zero. this results in the printing out of an empty string.

the following code will fix the problem, but for the future, i do not recommend using `.available()` - it is rather unreliable in my experience. you should check if data is available by simplying attempting to read data.

Client.java:

```
    one:while(true)
    {
        str = clientStream.readLine();
        b =str.getBytes();
        bos.write(b);
        bos.flush();

        while (bis.available() <= 0)
        {
            // wait for data!
        }

        a=bis.available();
        b = new byte[a];
        bis.read(b);
        str = new String (b);
        str.trim();
        System.out.print("The server says: "+str);
        if (str.equals("BYE"))
        {
            bis.read(b);
            str = new String (b);
            System.out.print("The server says: "+str);
            break one;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Alex
And I'll keep in mind your suggestion while naming variables in future :)